# Is it possible to pass an id parameter to AndroidViewModel in a public method without Factory?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I was looking at the BasicSample app from Android Architecture components sample. In the ProductViewModel.java file, some comments read:

> It's not
>             actually necessary in this case, as the product ID can be passed in a public method.

Based on my understanding of the comment, I would like to know if it's possible to pass the productId to the ProductViewModel without using a factory, and how this can be done.

I have implemented Transformation, and I know I can pass a productId using switchMap. But I was looking for a way to initialize the model with a single id.

```
public class ProductViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final LiveData<ProductEntity> mObservableProduct;

    public ObservableField<ProductEntity> product = new ObservableField<>();

    private final int mProductId;

    private final LiveData<List<CommentEntity>> mObservableComments;

    public ProductViewModel(@NonNull Application application, DataRepository repository,
            final int productId) {
        super(application);
        mProductId = productId;

        mObservableComments = repository.loadComments(mProductId);
        mObservableProduct = repository.loadProduct(mProductId);
    }
```

....

```
   /**
     * A creator is used to inject the product ID into the ViewModel
     * <p>
     * This creator is to showcase how to inject dependencies into ViewModels. It's not
     * actually necessary in this case, as the product ID can be passed in a public method.
     */
    public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

        @NonNull
        private final Application mApplication;

        private final int mProductId;

        private final DataRepository mRepository;

        public Factory(@NonNull Application application, int productId) {
            mApplication = application;
            mProductId = productId;
            mRepository = ((BasicApp) application).getRepository();
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) new ProductViewModel(mApplication, mRepository, mProductId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to the sample, when the comment says:

> the product ID can be passed in a public method

this is referring to the fact you can create a public setter method.

Since the `productId` is used to get a LiveData from your database, you should use a `switchMap`, as you mentioned. This is because `switchMap` allows you to lookup and update what a `LiveData` is pointing to, without needing to re-setup observers. If you didn't use a `switchMap`, you'd need to tell your Activity to observe the newly looked-up `LiveData`, and potentially stop observing the old `LiveData` object. [More description of this is included in the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html#transform_livedata).

One more note - the factory is also useful here because you're passing in or *injecting* the `DataRepository` dependency via the constructor. This is a preferable way to get the repository into the class because it's easy to mock the repository when testing.

With that in mind, if you wanted to do this would a factory, your code might look something like:

```
public class ProductViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final LiveData<ProductEntity> mProduct;
    private final LiveData<List<CommentEntity>> mComments;
    private final MutableLiveData<Integer> mProductId = new MutableLiveData<>();


    public ProductViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        // Have some way to get your repository, this is not great for testing...
        Repository repository = ((BasicApp) application).getRepository();

            mProduct = Transformations.switchMap(mProductId, id -> {
            return repository.loadProduct(id);
        }

            mComments = Transformations.switchMap(mComments, id -> {
            return repository.loadComments(id);
        }
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
       mProductId.setValue(productId); // This will trigger both of those switchMap statements
    }

}
```

Comment: Just in case someone is confused. It should be `mComments = Transformations.switchMap(mProductId, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Where does the **productId** come from ?

- If it's loaded from repository (database or web services), you don't have to expose it on ViewModel I guess.
- If it's a "dynamic" value, stored into SharedPreferences or setted from views, you can expose a Setter as follow

.

```
 public void setProductId(int productId) {
       if(mProductId == -1) { // or check mObservableComments 
              mProductId = productId;
              mObservableComments = repository.loadComments(mProductId);
              mObservableProduct = repository.loadProduct(mProductId);
       }
}
```